# Ajax call only working on first page of webgrid

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, pagination, webgrid

Hi all,

I have a webgrid that has pagination. One of the column displays an icon that can be clicked and will trigger an ajax call. The ajax call works fine on the first page of the webgrid but it doesn't seem to be working on the next pages. I don't think it's even hitting the ajax call, the display would also jump on the top of the page. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong or how I can make it work on the other pages of the webgrid as well?

```
var Grid = new WebGrid(canPage: true, canSort: false, rowsPerPage: 25, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "gridContent");
Grid.Bind(Model.DataList);
Grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.NextPrevious);

var gridColumns = new List<WebGridColumn>();

gridColumns.Add(PaymentGrid.Column(columnName: "WavFile", header: " ", format:@<text>
@if (item.WavFile != null && item.WavFile != "")
{ <a href="#" id="audiobtn" class="audiobtn"><img src="~/Content/audio.png" 
title="Download" alt="@item.WavFile" /></a> }
else
{ @Html.Raw("<img src=\"/Content/audiooff.png\" />") }</text>));
gridColumns.Add(Grid.Column(columnName: "EmployeeID", header: "EmpID"));
gridColumns.Add(Grid.Column(columnName: "LastName", header: "Last", canSort: 
true));
gridColumns.Add(Grid.Column(columnName: "FirstName", header: "First", canSort: true));

<div id="gridContent">
@Grid.GetHtml(
tableStyle: "table table-striped table-hover",
headerStyle: "",
footerStyle: "",
alternatingRowStyle: "",
rowStyle: "",
mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
columns: Grid.Columns(gridColumns.ToArray())
) 
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

$(".audiobtn").click(function (e) {

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "/EmployeeInfo/VoiceAuthorization",
data: { audio: $(this).find('img').attr('alt') },
async: false,
cache: false,
success: function (response) {

if (e.button == 0) {
$("#ContextMenu").css('left', e.pageX + 5);
$("#ContextMenu").css('top', e.pageY + 5);
$("#ContextMenu").fadeIn(100); 
} 
},
error: function (error) {
alert('Invalid wav file');
console.log(error);
}
});

return false;
});

$("#ContextMenu").click(function () {
$("#ContextMenu").fadeOut(80); 
});

$(document).click(function (e) {
if (e.target.id != 'audiobtn' && !$('#audiobtn').find(e.target).length) {
$("#ContextMenu").hide(); 
} 
    });

    return false;
    });
});
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It not work due the pages next to the first are generated dynamically.

Replace the code `$(".audiobtn").click(function (e) { ... });` with `$("body").on("click", ".audiobtn", function () { .. });` and should work.

Comment: I'm trying to implement the same thing but I want to make the webgrid row clickable instead of a button. This works with a button but it doesn't work on webgrid row. It only works on first page but not on other pages.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that in the second grid page the jquery is not initialized, so do this

change this

```
<a href="#" id="audiobtn" class="audiobtn"><img src="~/Content/audio.png" 
title="Download" alt="@item.WavFile" /></a>
```

by this (a callAjax() function was added to the onClick event)

```
<a href="#" id="audiobtn" class="audiobtn" onclick="callAjax(@item.WavFile)"><img src="~/Content/audio.png" 
title="Download" alt="@item.WavFile" /></a>
```

Then change this

```
    $(".audiobtn").click(function (e) {

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "/EmployeeInfo/VoiceAuthorization",
data: { audio: $(this).find('img').attr('alt') },
async: false,
cache: false,
success: function (response) {
```

By this

```
function callAjax(param) {

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "/EmployeeInfo/VoiceAuthorization",
data: { audio: param },
async: false,
cache: false,
success: function (response) {
```